# IEEE 754: why predicates == and != are not signaling?

Tags: ieee-754

Note: understanding IEEE 754. Please be patient.

IEEE 754-2008:

> Table 5.2 lists five unordered-signaling predicates and their negations that cause an invalid operation exception when the relation is unordered. That invalid operation exception defends against unexpected quiet NaNs arising in programs written using the
> standard predicates {<, <=, >=, >} and their negations, without considering the possibility of a quiet NaN operand.

Question: why `==` and `!=` predicates are not in the `{}` list? The unexpected quiet NaNs can arise in programs written using predicates `==` and `!=` as well.

Comment: @John Bollinger Any ideas?

Comment: It should be noted that the operations in table 5.2 include signaling equal-to and not-equal-to operations.  It may be, then, that the operator list in the text just inadvertently omits `==` operation.  If it's intentionally omitted then I'm not quite seeing what the quoted text is trying to say.

Comment: (1) The `=` and `≠` predicates are defined as `compareQuietEqual` and `compareQuietNotEqual` (Table 5.1). (2) Re: _inadvertently omits_: it seems that IEEE 754-2008 (as well as IEEE 754-2019) _inadvertently_ classifies `convertFromInt` and `convertToIntegerXXX` as arithmetic operations (5.4.1 Arithmetic operations) instead of conversion operations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Question: why == and != predicates are not in the {} list?

Because it is a list of traditionally-signaling predicates, and the `==` and `!=` operations are traditionally quiet.  The `{}` list is not a parenthetical -- it is an enumeration of the operations being described.  The spec does define signaling `equal` and `notEqual` predicates, and these are listed in table 5.2, but they simply are not what the quoted sentence is talking about.  The spec also defines quiet versions of `Greater`, *etc*. (listed in table 5.3); these are of course not what the quoted sentence is talking about either.

*All* the signaling versions, including `compareSignalingEqual()` and `compareSignalingNotEqual()`, have the property that they are

> intended for use by programs *not* written to take into
> account the possibility of NaN operands

(introduction to table 5.2; emphasis in the original).

Comment: Any ideas why the `==` and `!=` operations are traditionally quiet? (The `==` and `!=` are not  defended against unexpected quiet NaNs by raising invalid operation exception.)

Comment: I'm not sure, @pmor, but perhaps because `x != x` is a longtime conventional test for whether a value is NaN.  Inasmuch as this may have its roots in the historical development of FP hardware, it might be a good question for [Retrocomputing SE](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/).