# Is it considered normal that f = NAN may cause raising floating-point exceptions?

Tags: c, floating-point, c11, floating-point-exceptions, c23

C2x (as well as previous):

> The macro `NAN` is defined if and only if the implementation supports quiet NaNs for the `float` type. It expands to a constant expression of type float representing a quiet NaN.

Sample code (t0a.c)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <fenv.h>

#if _MSC_VER && ! __clang__ && ! __INTEL_COMPILER
#pragma fenv_access (on)
#else
#pragma STDC FENV_ACCESS ON
#endif

void print_fe_excepts_raised(void)
{
    printf("exceptions raised ");
    if (fetestexcept(FE_DIVBYZERO))  printf(" FE_DIVBYZERO");
    if (fetestexcept(FE_INEXACT))    printf(" FE_INEXACT");
    if (fetestexcept(FE_INVALID))    printf(" FE_INVALID");
    if (fetestexcept(FE_OVERFLOW))   printf(" FE_OVERFLOW");
    if (fetestexcept(FE_UNDERFLOW))     printf(" FE_UNDERFLOW");
    if (fetestexcept(FE_ALL_EXCEPT)==0) printf(" none");
    printf("\n");
}

int main(void)
{
    float f;

    feclearexcept(FE_ALL_EXCEPT);
    f = NAN;
    print_fe_excepts_raised();
    (void)f;
    return 0;
}
```

Invocations:

```
# msvc (version 19.29.30133 for x64)
$ cl t0a.c /std:c11 /Za /fp:strict && t0a.exe
exceptions raised  FE_INEXACT FE_INVALID FE_OVERFLOW

# clang on Windows (version 13.0.0)
$ clang t0a.c -std=c11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -ffp-model=strict && ./a.exe
exceptions raised  FE_INEXACT FE_INVALID FE_OVERFLOW

# gcc on Windows (version 11.2.0)
$ gcc t0a.c -std=c11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra  && ./a.exe
exceptions raised  none

# gcc on Linux (version 11.2.0)
$ gcc t0a.c -std=c11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra  && ./a.out
exceptions raised  none

# clang on Linux (version 13.0.0)
$ clang t0a.c -std=c11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -ffp-model=strict && ./a.out
exceptions raised  none
```

For msvc and clang on Windows: this is because:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\corecrt_math.h:94:9
#define NAN ((float)(INFINITY * 0.0F))

C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\corecrt_math.h:90:9
#define INFINITY ((float)(_HUGE_ENUF * _HUGE_ENUF))

C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\corecrt_math.h:87:13
#define _HUGE_ENUF 1e+300 // _HUGE_ENUF*_HUGE_ENUF must overflow
```

Here we see that `NAN` "expands to a constant expression of type float representing a quiet NaN". Which implies that `f = NAN` may cause floating-point exceptions. However, `f = NAN` is usually seen as "writing to memory". Hence, people may wonder: "how writing to memory may cause raising floating-point exceptions?".

Comment: Preliminarily, the fact that a macro expands to a constant expression does not require its value to be computed at compile time.  If the expansion contains operators and if the context permits, then the operations involved *may* be evaluated at runtime.  In that case, it can be the computation of the floating-point NaN that causes an FP exception to be raised, as opposed to that being an effect of the assignment of the result.

Comment: So Microsoft's headers define a NAN but it's not quiet. You found a bit where they deviate from the standard. Let's ignore wondering people and focus on your question. Hmm, what is your question actually?

Comment: Actually, the value produced by the expression is most likely a quiet NaN. [The whole thing seems fairly complicated.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18118408/what-is-the-difference-between-quiet-nan-and-signaling-nan)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the record, this ...

> > The macro `NAN` is defined if and only if the implementation supports quiet NaNs for the `float` type. It expands to a constant expression of type float representing a quiet NaN.

... is C17 7.12/5, and it probably has the same or similar numbering in C2x.

---

**Updated**

The fact that when used with MSVC or Clang on Windows, your test program causes the `FE_INVALID` FP exception to be raised <s>suggests that the combination of</s>

- Microsoft's C standard library and runtime environment with
- the MSVC and Clang compilers and
- the options you are specifying to those

is causing a signaling NaN to be generated and used as an arithmetic operand.  I would agree that that is an unexpected result, probably indicating that these combinations fail to fully conform to the C language specification in this area.

has nothing to do with whether the resulting NaN is a quiet or a signaling one.  The misconception there is that the `FE_INVALID` flag would be raised only as a consequence of generating or operating on a signaling NaN.  That is not the case.

For one thing, IEEE-754 does not define any case in which a signaling NaN is generated.  All defined operations that produce an NaN produce a quiet NaN, including operations in which one operand is a signaling NaN (so MSVC and Clang on Windows almost certainly do produce a quiet NaN as the value of the `NAN` macro).  Most operations with at least one signaling NaN as an operand do, by default, cause the FE_INVALID flag to be raised, but that is not the usual reason for that flag to be raised.

Rather, under default exception handling, the `FE_INVALID` flag is raised simply because of a request to compute an operation with no defined result, such as infinity times 0.  The result will be a quiet NaN.  Note that this does not include operations with at least one NaN operand, which *do* have a defined result: a quiet NaN in many cases, unordered / false for comparisons, and other results in a few cases.

With that for context, it is important to recognize that just because `NAN` expands to a constant expression (in a conforming C implementation) does not mean that the value of that expression is computed at compile time.  Indeed, given the specifications for MSVC's and Clang's strict fp modes, I would expect those modes to disable most, if not all, compile-time computation of FP expressions (or at minimum to propogate FP status flags as if the computations were performed at run time).

Thus, raising `FE_INVALID` is not necessarily an effect of the assignment in `f = NAN`.  If (as in Microsoft's C standard library) `NAN` expands to an expression involving arithmetic operations then the exception should be raised as a result of the evaluating that expression, notwithstanding that the resulting NaN is quiet.  At least in implementations that claim full conformance with IEC 60559 by defining the `__STDC_IEC_559__` feature-test macro.

Therefore, although I will not dispute that

> people may wonder: "how writing to memory may cause raising floating-point exceptions?".

, no convincing evidence has been presented to suggest that such causation has been observed.

Nevertheless, the value represented by a particular appearance of `NAN` in an expression that is evaluated has some kind of physical manifestation.  It is plausible for that to be in an FPU register, and storing a signaling NaN from an FPU register to memory indeed could cause a FP exception to be raised on some architectures.

Comment: Re: _I would expect ..._: According to tests, they indeed disable most, if not all, compile-time computation of FP expressions. However, this is [not mentioned in the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/fp-specify-floating-point-behavior?view=msvc-170).

Comment: It may not be mentioned explicitly in the documentation, @pmor, but it is a predictable requirement for implementing the behavior that *is* documented.  In any case, it is not safe or reasonable to assume that just because something can be done, it will be done.

Comment: FYI: According to tests clang under `-ffp-model=strict` keeps computing FP expressions at compile time.

Comment: If that's indeed so, @pmor, then Clang must be going to a lot of trouble to also capture the  the resulting FP status at compile time and re-apply it at run time.  Which, of course, is a valid way of doing it, and that also contradicts the premise that FP exceptions arising from the computation of the `NAN` expression should not be visible at run time.

Comment: Please (try to) address https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67972598/ieee-754-why-predicates-and-are-not-signaling.

Comment: Re: _Clang must be going to a lot of trouble_: also doing FP computations at compile time rather than at run time can be error prone because [logic implementing FP operations in compiler's front end](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/llvm/blob/2c4ca6832fa6b306ee6a7010bfb80a3f2596f824/lib/Support/APFloat.cpp) (usually arbitrary precision) usually is not formally verified (and, hence, may be subject of errors), while the logic implementing FP operations in Intel CPUs [is formally verified](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~jrh13/slides/nijmegen-21jun02/slides.pdf) (and, hence, free of errors).

Comment: Re: _to disable most, if not all, compile-time computation of FP expressions_. Btw, because of that `float x = 0.0f + 0.0f;` placed at file scope leads to `error C2099: initializer is not a constant` despite the fact that `0.0f + 0.0f` does not lead to raising of floating-point exceptions nor may produce different results under non-default rounding modes. How can you comment on this?