# Why stdio.h, stdlib.h, string.h declare size_t, NULL, etc. instead of #include <stddef.h>?

Tags: c, language-lawyer, header-files, c-standard-library

The headers `stdio.h`, `stdlib.h`, `string.h` declare `size_t`, `NULL`, etc.

Why declaring `size_t`, `NULL`, etc. instead of `#include <stddef.h>`?

Comment: Maybe because the effect is the same, but the compilation time is a bit shorter.

Comment: @Dialecticus To compare with: "The header <tgmath.h> includes the headers <math.h> and <complex.h> and defines several type-generic macros." (N2596, 7.25)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why declaring size_t, NULL, etc. instead of `#include <stddef.h>`?

Per C17 7.19/3, `stddef.h` *does* define `NULL`, so the question is unfounded.  Inasmuch as the premise seems to be in part that the role served by `stddef.h` makes it a good place for `NULL` to be defined, the standard committee seems to agree.

`stdio.h` (7.21.1/2), `stdlib.h` (7.22/3), and `string.h` (7.24.1/1) also define `NULL`.  As to why this is, I am inclined to say that a combination of historical variation in which headers defined which macros plays a part, but it is also the case that each of these headers declare at least one function whose arguments and / or return value attribute specific significance to null pointers.  For example, `fopen()` returns a null pointer when it fails.  Although it is not essential to use the macro `NULL` to represent a null pointer constant, it is highly idiomatic, so ensuring that these headers define it makes it accessible in at least most of the standard library cases where it will be wanted, without requiring inclusion of a header just for that purpose.

Similar applies for `size_t`, less the historical variation angle.

#### Addendum

Upon review, I think I initially misread the question.  However, to the extent that it inquires about why the spec says that `stdio.h` *etc*. define various identifiers that are also defined by `stddef.h`, when it could instead specify that those headers `#include <stddef.h>`, I think it still largely comes down to each header providing all the declarations it needs, so as to stand substantially on its own.

Additionally, however, if the spec said (for example) that `string.h` included `stddef.h` then that would make all identifiers specified to be declared by the latter reserved (in various senses) in any translation unit that includes the former, pursuant to section 7.1.3 of the spec.  By instead specifying that particular identifiers are declared or defined in `string.h`, only those specific identifiers are reserved by inclusion of `string.h`.

Comment: Re: "a combination of historical variation": perhaps traditions? The similar case: predicates `==` and `!=` are "[traditionally quiet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69943598/1778275)".

Comment: @pmor, although there is a similar flavor of behaving as people have learned to expect and of not breaking existing code, I would characterize "historical variation" as the *absence* of a consistent tradition.

Answer (score 0):

Because that's what the C standard says to do:

http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf

> ISO/IEC 9899:TC3 Committee Draft — Septermber 7, 2007 WG14/N1256
>
> 7.19 Input/output `<stdio.h>`
>
> 7.19.1 Introduction
>
> 1 The header `<stdio.h>` declares three types, several macros, and many functions for performing input and output.
>
> 2 The types declared are `size_t` (described in 7.17);
>
> *[...]*
>
> 3 The macros are `NULL` (described in 7.17);

7.17 is in fact the section for `<stddef.h>`.

Comment: C99 is no longer well characterized as *the* C standard.  However, although the section numbers are different in the current standard, it says the same thing about which headers define `NULL`.